# Unable to use a variable key index in an object call

Tags: javascript

I have a line in JavaScript, which is working fine:

```
var fetchedValue = getMyData(available_values.data[0].actualKey);
```

But if I replace the static portion **actualKey** with the dynamic variable **var1** and use it, it gives error that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

```
var var1 = "actualKey";
var fetchedValue = getMyData(available_values.data[0].eval(var1));
```

I tried writing multiple occurrences, such as below, but everything is giving the same error:

```
var fetchedValue = getMyData(available_values.data[0].eval({var1}));
```

and

```
var fetchedValue = getMyData(available_values.data[0].eval(${var1}));
```

Comment: Use bracket notation as Unmitigated says, and _**don't** use eval!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation. See [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```js
available_values.data[0][var1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const myPropName = "actualKey";
var fetchedValue = getMyData(available_values.data[0][myPropName]);
```